# How to count the occurrences of all strings in array and replace the last occurrences each time is repeated?

Tags: c++, qt, file

I want to create an application using Qt that allows me to browse a text file containing multiple lines of repeated strings, store the content in an array, and count each time a string is repeated. I want to replace the last two occurrences with '-' if that string is repeated more than two times. If that string is repeated just twice, I can just replace the last occurrence with '-'.

I just found out how to count the number of occurrences of a string in an array, but it's not what I need.

**Note: I have to ignore the first string occurrences and the last.**

## My Code So Far

```
    void MushMushPlugin::browse()
{
    QString filename = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(
        this,
        QStringLiteral("Ouvrir Fichier"),
        "",
        "Fichiers Text(*.txt)");
    browseLine->setText(filename);
    qDebug() << "here: ";
    qDebug() << getFileContent(filename);
    QList<QString> myarray = getFileContent(filename);
    get_output_list(myarray);
}
QList<QString> MushMushPlugin::getFileContent(QString filename)
{
    QFile inputFile(filename);
    inputFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    QTextStream stream(&inputFile);
    stream.setCodec("UTF-8");
    QList<QString> fileContent;
    while (!stream.atEnd()) {
        QString line;
        line = stream.readLine();
        fileContent.append(line);
    }
    
    return fileContent;
    //return stream.readLine
}

QList<QString> MushMushPlugin::get_output_list(QList<QString> original_list)
{
    QList<QString> output_list = QList<QString>();
    qDebug() << original_list;
    //return m_array;
    QList<QString> tmp_list = QList<QString>();
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < original_list.size()-1; i++) {
        tmp_list.append(original_list[i]);
        if (original_list[i] == original_list[i+1]) {
            tmp_list.append(original_list[i+1]);
        }
        else {
            output_list.append(tmp_list);
            tmp_list = QList<QString>();
        }
    }

    qDebug() << output_list;
    return output_list;
}

QList<QString> MushMushPlugin::replace_with_underscore(QList<QString> duplicatedList)
{
    QList<QString> m_array = duplicatedList;
    if (m_array.size() > 2) {
        m_array.replace(m_array.size(), "-");
        m_array.replace(m_array.size()-1, "-");
    }
    if (m_array.size() == 2) {
        m_array.replace(m_array.size(), "-");
    }
    return m_array;
}
```

## Input Data

> aaa
>
> aaa
>
> aaa
>
> bbb
>
> bbb
>
> ccc
>
> ccc
>
> ccc
>
> ddd
>
> ddd
>
> ddd
>
> ddd

## Expected Output

> aaa
>
> **-**
>
> **-**
>
> bbb
>
> **-**
>
> ccc
>
> **-**
>
> **-**
>
> ddd
>
> ddd
>
> **-**
>
> **-**

Comment: You could do this with essentially 4 lines of code using the proper container (`std::unordered_set<QString>` or `std::set<QString>` if there is no hash for the former).  The rest of your code is superfluous -- what does making Widgets have to do with the issue?

Comment: @Scheff Thank you. 
I replace it